# dpkg-buildpackage: how to include .so files in the source pack

Tags: packaging, dpkg

I want to package a third party application which contains .so files.
When I build the package with dpkg-buildpackage, the .so files are excluded from the generated source package.

I don't have an .orig file. So, I use "3.0 (native)" in debian/source.

First I had these messages:

```
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library...
```

So, I included "override_dh_makeshlibs" and "override_dh_shlibdeps" in the debian/rules file.

man dpgk-source suggest to use "3.0 (quilt)" in debian/source but I don't have a .orig file, just a tar with the files in it.

I've tried to setup a debian/include-binaries file none the less (with "path_to.so" in it), but that didn't help.

debian/rules:

```
%:
dh $@

override_dh_strip:
    @echo "Not running dh_strip"

override_dh_makeshlibs:
    @echo "Not running dh_makeshlibs"

override_dh_shlibdeps:
    @echo "Not running dh_shlibdeps"
```

debian/source/format:

```
3.0 (native)
```

build command:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -aamd64 -us -uc
```

I'd expect the source package to include all files but it's missing the .so files.

The deb file is built correctly.

**[EDIT: Partial Solution]**
I've managed to create a deb with upstream source by manually creating the orig file before building the deb.

In the source directory:

changelog:

```
make sure that the version number has a revision.
```

sources/format:

```
3.0 (quilt)
```

source/include-binaries:

```
path_to.so
```

commands:

```
VERSION=$(dpkg-parsechangelog -S Version | sed -rne 's,([^-\+]+)+(\+dfsg)*.*,\1,p'i)
SOURCE=$(dpkg-parsechangelog -S Source)
UPSTREAM_PACKAGE=${SOURCE}_${VERSION}.orig.tar.gz

rm -f ../${UPSTREAM_PACKAGE}
tar czvf ../${UPSTREAM_PACKAGE} --exclude=debian --exclude=Makefile

dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -aamd64 -us -uc
```

**Is there a way to automate this?**

I don't know if or how this is possible in the debian/rules file or in a Makefile.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I came up with.

Create your project as you want it to be packaged. I assume you know which debian files are needed to successfully package your project.

These files are created or adapted:
debian/source/format:

```
3.0 (quilt)
```

debian/rules:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# -*- makefile -*-
# https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#s-debianrules
# https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/debhelper/debhelper.7.en.html

# Uncomment this to turn on verbose mode.
#export DH_VERBOSE=1

version := $(shell dpkg-parsechangelog -S Version | sed -rne 's,([^-\+]+)+(\+dfsg)*.*,\1,p'i)
source := $(shell dpkg-parsechangelog -S Source)
upstreampck := $(source)_$(version).orig.tar.gz

clean:
    @ echo CLEAN
    rm -f ../$(upstreampck)
    tar czf ../$(upstreampck) --exclude=debian --exclude=.pc .
    dh_testdir
    dh_auto_clean
    dh_clean 

build:
    @ echo BUILD: nothing to do here
    #dh_testdir
    #dh_auto_configure
    #dh_auto_build
    #dh_auto_test

binary:
    @ echo BINARY
    dh_testroot
    dh_prep
    dh_install
    dh_installdocs
    dh_installchangelogs 
    dh_installexamples
    dh_installman
    dh_link
    dh_compress
    dh_fixperms
    dh_installdeb
    dh_gencontrol
    dh_md5sums
    dh_builddeb

.PHONY: build clean binary
```

Update the cangelog and make sure to add a revision number to the upstream version:

```
dch -i -D stable -u low -M -p
```

Build the package:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -us -uc -aamd64 --source-option=--include-binaries
```

This will generate the orig file and the debian/source/include-binaries file.

All next builds can be done with:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -us -uc -aamd64
```